# Alert me How to split HTTP data into parallel branch and execute further steps in logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have `HTTP call` which call API and `gives 500 records`.

> For 500 records its taking to much long so i'm thinking to branch it
>   in 5 different branches where i will pass 100 records each to execute
>   everything in less time ,what is suggestion ?

I want to `create branches which will process 100 records for each branch` but `how to send 100 separate records to each branch?`

I want to do this to save my execution time , i have also tried concurrency in foreach but still its taking too much time to process 500 records , so i though i can split those records into branches

[image]

where exactly i can use `SplitOn`

```
"HTTP_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "headers": {
                                "Authorization": "@{concat('Bearer ',variables('accesstoken'))}",
                                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "demovalues"
                            },
                            "method": "GET",
                            "uri": "http://demo"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Set_variable_AccessToken": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Http"
                    },



                     "foreach": "@body('HTTP_2')?['results']",
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Increment_variable_SkipVariable": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        }
```

For `SplitOn` property I tried to add like this - but while saving logic app getting error.

```
 "HTTP_2": {
                            "inputs": {
                                "headers": {
                                    "Authorization": "@{concat('Bearer ',variables('accesstoken'))}",
                                    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "demovalues"
                                },
                                "method": "GET",
                                "uri": "http://demo"
                            },
                            "runAfter": {
                                "Set_variable_AccessToken": [
                                    "Succeeded"
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "Http",
                            "splitOn": "@Body('HTTP_2')?['results']",
                        }
```

> error getting after adding- The request content is not valid and could
>   not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'splitOn' on object of
>   type 'FlowTemplateAction'. Path
>   'properties.definition.actions.Run_the_code_until_all_records_completed_with_each_500_interations.actions.HTTP_2.splitOn',
>   line 1, position 494638.'

Comment: where to use SplitOn in my example inside HTTP_2 or inside foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic app provide a `SplitOn` property in your trigger to debatch the array. It's for when you want to process an array or any repeated element in the message and process them separately and reduce the execution time if with for each loop.

For a basic use, you could refer to the official doc:[Trigger multiple runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#trigger-multiple-runs). And if you are calling sql or Azure table etc to get records, you could use two logic apps to implement it. This wiki could help you:[Azure LogicApp Debatching](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37351.azure-logicapp-debatching-splitting-messages-and-process-them-separately.aspx).

The advantage of this approach is that every child message immediately starts processing independently from the others. If one message fails during further processing, it does not impact the others and exception handling can be done on the level of the child message.

**Remind** if with `SplitOn` property, it will generate a separate instance of the logic app and process individual orders Parallel.

**Update:** Below is a sample I used to process storage table entities. Both are HTTP triggered, the parent one to get the table value and then call the child one(set the `Content-Type`=`application/json` with the entities body).

[image]

And the child one just set the `"splitOn": "@triggerBody()['value']"` under the trigger. **Remind it could be only set with trigger.**

[image]

**And here is the result. The parent will get four entities value, the the child logic will be split to four parallel one.**

[image]

[image]

**From this below pic you could find the each branch only get one value then after the HTTP trigger you could add same actions.**

[image]

Comment: my problem statement is for 500 records its taking to much long so i'm thinking to branch it in 5 different branches where i will pass 100 records each to execute everything in less time ,what is suggestion ?

Comment: @Neo, I don't think it could be split to 5 branches, that's why I recommend you use SplitOn .

Comment: in HTTP_2 body I have results array how to apply SpiltOn prop?

body('HTTP_2')?['results'] how to do it?

Comment: Use the SplitOn in the HTTP trigger if you use it.

Comment: error getting after adding-
 The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'splitOn' on object of type 'FlowTemplateAction'. Path 'properties.definition.actions.Run_the_code_until_all_records_completed_with_each_500_interations.actions.HTTP_2.splitOn', line 1, position 494638.'.

Comment: What's your way to get records? Or add some pics.

Comment: @Neo,  I have updated the answer, hope this could help you to use spliton.